# selecting parent blocks with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<tr>
<td class="message">
    <p>This is a test post</p>
</td>
<td class="metadata">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="">#1</a><br/>
        <span>12.03.2012</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
         <a href="" class="light-button quote">Quote</a>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have multiple posts on a page and I want to implement quoting a post with js. When a user clicks on the quote button it should take the paragraph text
What I tried so far:

```
$('a.quote').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('.message > p').text();      
});`
```

but this is not working.It returns an empty string.

edit: I made it work
`$(this).closest('td').prev().children('p.thread-message').html();`

Comment: for starters, you are not looking for the parent block, but for a sibling td

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$('a.quote').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     alert($(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('p').html());      
});
```

​
Here is the jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7tfMK/9/

Comment: omg i have multiple posts on the page, i need to get the p relative to the quote button , because otherwise i will get strange data

Comment: @Mythriel: Use some divs instead of td / tr and group the related data.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parents('td').siblings('.message').children('p').text()`

You need to either go all the way up to the parent TR as in @Shyju's post, or go to the parent TD and grab its sibling.

Answer (score 0):

This will work;

```
var quote = $(this).parents('tr').first().find('.message p').text();
```

See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XvPbh/).

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this

```
$('.message > p', $(this)).text();
```

This is untested, and wrapping `this` into jQuery object might not be necessary.

Comment: This is equivalent to `$(this).find('.message > p')`, but `.message > p` is not a child of the button.